# Vuejs Set operation on key failed: target is readonly

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-props

I use Laravel9 with Vuejs3.
I have a blade view that passes php variables to vue component:

```
<subscription-form 
location="{{ $props['location'] }}"
orientation="{{ $props['orientation'] }}"
/>
```

In my main vue that receive data, I have the following code in script setup:

```
const initProps = defineProps(['location', 'orientation']);

const values = reactive(initProps);
```

This parent vue call a component like this:

```
<component 
          v-bind:is="steps[step]"
          v-bind:formValues="values"
></component>
```

The problem is that my reactive variable `values` is not accessible for writing in my child vues.
I have the error

```
[Vue warn] Set operation on key "location" failed: target is readonly.
```

This happend when I do for exemple:

```
props.formValues.location = location;
```

It was working when I didn't have to pass php variable from my blade to the parent vue. But now I have data props at 2 levels from blade to main vue and then from main vue to child components, it is in readonly.

Help!

I tried to switch `initProps` or `values` variables from const type to var but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I did not use the new Composition API, but the error is basic, you have PROPs and PROPS are read only, they are not "normal" data (reactive) as on Options API

Answer (score 0):

I'm disappointed...
This was not working because of my defineProps() returning undefined
The problem was: THE CAPITAL LETTERS!
I changed `<subscription-form :initPropsValues="{{ json_encode($props) }}"/>`
to `<subscription-form :initprops="{{ json_encode($props) }}"/>`
And my defineProps() returns my object!
Why is that not working with caps?